# CoAP on Apache, CoAP Web Service

Tags: apache, http, proxy, webserver, coap

I am working with **CoAP** protocol on **IoT** but also I need a web service. I implemented the web service on **Apache** with **HTTP** protocol and a **Proxy** that converts *CoAP-HTTP* request and responses. But I don't want to use the Proxy to convert *CoAP-HTTP*. I want to implement directly **CoAP** web service. Do you have any idea about that. On **Apache** or different things. Just any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote `On Apache or different things`, I will here talk about the second option :). To implement the CoAP server itself, I would recommend either

- NodeJS with the [CoAP package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coap)
- Java implementation [Californium](https://www.eclipse.org/californium/), from Eclipse.org
- More complete list available at http://coap.technology/impls.html#server-side, see Server-side

And then handle the communication with your Apache HTTP server via WebSockets and REST APIs.
[coap.me](http://coap.me) is also great to run tests during development.